# Category Page Template - Can't get category ID

Tags: categories

I am creating a category template that uses WP_query to get posts from my custom post type...

```
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'mycpt' ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
?>

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How do i get the category id for the current category type?  I can get the category title with...

```
<?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?>
```

But how do I get the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a category archive, the "queried object" will have what you need.

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
var_dump($cat->cat_ID);
```

You can access it by means of `get_query_var()`:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
var_dump($cat);
```

You can also pull is straight from the `$wp_query` global:

```
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['cat']);
```

All of these assume that you are actually on a proper category archive page and that nothing has clobbered or otherwise corrupted the main query.